# Why am i getting a counter error in LaTeX?

Tags: theorems, amsthm

In LaTeX, I have,

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
 Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Some proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I am getting the error message: `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'Theorem' defined.`

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMS packages (primarily `amsthm`) modify the `newtheorem` command.  You called `newtheorem` before loading the packages, so the theorems weren't created properly.  Instead, just load the packages first, and then define the theorems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} Some theorem. \end{theorem}

\begin{proof} Some proof \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually newtheorem does not need amsthm it is in the latex kernel. Besides that your analysis is correct, when defined before loading amsthm the envs created is not in the manner amsthm redefines the theorem components to be, hence the error

Comment: @daleif I don't know if I knew that.  I pretty much always use the ams packages.  Thanks.